Resources for understanding non-unitary channels and operators
I need some resources to understand non-unitary channels and operators in depth in order to simulate non-unitary channels instead of unitary ones in some problems. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Are you looking for something more specific, or are you looking for general resources?

@FDGod I have a task to simulate a research paper that has been conducted using unitary channels but instead of unitary, I have to use non-unitary channels. also what simulation tools or quantum programming languages can be more useful to me?

Can you link the paper? As to simulating non-unitary behaviour, I would recommend using the Python package QiTiP

In case you are interested in simulating non-unitaries with the standard circuit model, you can use Stinespring dilation.
In brief, you employ auxiliary qubits entangled with a system of interest, generating so a (simulated) lack of information -- a.k.a. a non-unitary --, by ignoring (tracing out) the auxiliary system.
For a practical example, you may find helpful my paper - Section III.A, where I used Stinespring dilation to simulate Pauli noises.


Lecture Notes on the Theory of Open Quantum Systems by Lidar
The Theory of Quantum Information by Watrous
Principles of
Quantum Communication Theory:
A Modern Approach by Khatri & Wilde


Watrous, the author of The Theory of Quantum Information, also has an upcoming series General formulation of quantum information which is set to be a bit more beginner-friendly than his textbook.
